# Vertically centering text on all pages of document

Tags: page, definition

I have formatted one page of my document in a particular way. (including alignments) Now I want to have that particular setting for every page of my document. This would have been very easy if the page was an environment. (`\renewenvironment` would have solved my problem) My question is is there any way to renew the definitions of a page in the preamble itself so that they'll be held throughout the document for every page.

Here is the code -

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
\vspace*{\fill}
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thispagestyle`? `\pagestyle` for global setting?

Comment: I want every page to be vertically centered, I've a code ready with me, I just want it to be global.

Comment: I think `\pagestyle` won't work here. There are only four valid options for that command.

Comment: With `titlesec` you can define a new page style

Comment: But please clarify more! What do you mean by "vertically centered"? It is hard to imagine

Comment: @JouleV Please see the edit

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to have a title page?

Comment: No every page of my document is like that.

Comment: you have an explicit `\pagebreak` in your example, do you just need manual page breaking or do you need automatic page breaking?

Comment: Manual pagebreaks are needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how are automatic pagebreaks understood as there is no command to separate the texts on two pages and then what is the point of vertically centering the text.

Comment: @Niranjan so in that case it is most natural to make yourself an environment for each page (like beamer's frame)  where the begin and end code are `{\cleapage\vspace*{\fill}} {\par\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage}`

Comment: So there isn't any other way? Because my document is ready and I'll have to manually add this environment at the beginning and at the end of every page. That is equal to adding this code at the beginning of every page. I was thinking of a shorter way...

Comment: if you have `\pagebreak` now it's a single edit to make them all `\end{mypage} \begin{mypage}` you could do it other ways but that seems the most natural markup.

Comment: I had a thought of this. I was just thinking whether one can do this without any specific command in the text and just by pre-defining a 'page' itself in the preamble.

Comment: Your question is much more specific than your title implies. Consider changing it to something like "Vertically centering text on all pages of document"

Comment: @erik Done! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using manual pagebreaks, you can define `\mypagebreak` to fill the remaining space, start a new page, and add vertical space on the next page. However, this would require you to manually provide a `pagebreak` *every* time. To automate this (in case you overflow and want the subsequent page to be vertically centered as well), you can use the `atbegshi` package to ensure space is added at every new page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument{\topskip=0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
\AtEndDocument{\vspace{\fill}}
\providecommand{\mypagebreak}{\par\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage}
\AtBeginShipout{\par\vspace*{\fill}}
\begin{document}
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
\mypagebreak
More TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

\mypagebreak
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: _**THIS**_ was the solution I was looking for!! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

There are document classes that are vertically centered by default:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\geometry{paper=a4paper,vmargin=0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

foo
\framebreak

bar
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: beamer generally adds extra info to each page and setting beamer at the top of this master file would still require changes throughout the existing pages this question was "Given a scripted document" how to globally change all the pages to vertically centered reflow just from the initial page definition (much like a word processor could)

Comment: Sorry, I want my document in article class.